# Will closed form solution be always overfitting?

Tags: machine-learning, regression, linear-regression

Since we have closed form solutions to some machine learning problems, like linear regression. They have higher complexity of O(D^3) (D being the number of features derived from inputs), but will the solution derived using closed form will be overfitting always?

1. I know that closed form solution takes longer computation power, which may not be feasible for larger number of features.
2. I also understand that gradient descent, stochaistic gradient descent etc.. generate close enough solutions with lesser complexity.

Just wanted to understand, whether using the closed form solution will be beneficial at all?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes: in short, you've found the optimal solution for that data set.  A closed-form solution on a *sample* of the population will be, by definition, over-fitted to that sample.  Note, however, that if the sample is the *entire* population, your solution will be necessarily optimal.

The various "sneak up on it" solutions (e.g. gradient descent) are specifically designed to find the *same* solution by heuristic means, within any arbitrarily small error that you specify.  This is the soul of numerical analysis.  :-)

For most purposes, the closed-form solution is beneficial only if you require the nicety of an exact solution for further theoretical derivation.  In some cases, it's also faster for prediction (forward-pass only), since it has far fewer weights.  However, prediction is generally limited by I/O speed, not by the model complexity.

Answer (score 1):

This is not true in general, but will be true in practice in some cases.

Say you've got millions of observations, and thousands of features, and you fit a linear regression to the first principal component of your design matrix.  This is the first sort of situation where the closed-form is not overfit: **N is much greater than P**

Alternatively, there is a closed-form solution to the ridge regression.  It R, it is `solve(crossprod(X) + lambda * diag(rep(1, nrow(x))) %*% t(X) %*% y`.  Cross-validating to select an optimal lambda will very often be faster than gradient descent.  This is the second sort of situation:  **The closed-form solution involves a hyperparameter**.  Generalized additive models are sort of like this as well.